# Why does the floated span drop?

Tags: html, css, firefox

This code will work fine in Webkit (chrome) but not in firefox, where the second span will drop, do you know why?

```
<div id="sbar">
    <span id="status">Some Text</span>
    <span id="mlog" style="float: right;">Some text in the right</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try reversing the two spans.

```
<div id="sbar">
    <span id="mlog" style="float: right;">Some text in the right</span>
    <span id="status">Some Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... reversing makes it work cause with floats, you need to arrange your elements like a stack that the browser can pick up -

so when floating left

A

B

C

will float to ABC -

A

AB

ABC

when all floated right will give you CBA, as in

A

BA

CBA

I've seen this implemented in firefox, haven't checked webkit. You can be safe with this, though.

Answer (score 1):

> This code will work fine in Webkit (chrome) but not in firefox

WebKit is wrong. The standard specifies the right-float must go down a line.

For explanation, see [CSS: Three Column Layout problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533607/css-three-column-layout-problem/533671).

Answer (score 1):

> This code will work fine in Webkit
>   (chrome) but not in firefox, where the
>   second span will drop, do you know
>   why?

Yes. The behavior of a floated element will fall below a non-floated element that comes before it in the code. Others have given you the fixes already.

Answer (score 1):

Can propose other solution without reversing. It does work in different browsers

```
<div id="sbar" style="position:relative;">
    <span id="status">Some Text</span>
    <span id="mlog" style="position:absolute; top:0;right:0;">Some text in the right</span>
</div>
```