# css problem with unordered lists (as usual with IE)

Tags: html, css

I am using un-ordered lists that nests some divs to show the desired output on screen. I am using css to style them and they seem to look perfect on chrome and firefox. But in IE(8) it looks there is a problem which I was unable to locate.

I am using the below CSS

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .ur_container {width:980px; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
        .ur_container ul.bx_grp {list-style-type: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
        .ur_container ul.bx_lnx {list-style-type: none; padding: 5px; margin: 0px; }

        .bx_grp {border:1px solid #c5c5c5; background-color: yellow; margin:0; padding:0;}
        .bx_grp_header {background-color: #d6d6d6; border-bottom:1px solid #acacac;}
        .bx_grp_title {float: left; font: bold 11px Arial; padding:5px;}
        .bx_grp_options {float: right; font: 10px Arial; padding: 5px;}
        .bx_grp_options a{color: #125B93; text-decoration: none; }          

        .bx_lnx {padding:0px; background-color: red;}
        .bx_lnx_header {font:11px Arial; color:#333;}
        .bx_lnx_title {float: left;}
        .bx_lnx_refno {background-color:#333; color: fff; padding: 1px; margin-right: 5px; }
        .bx_lnx_options {float: right;}
        .bx_lnx_options a {color: #258CF4; text-decoration: none;}
        .bx_lnx_url {font: 9px Arial; color: #999; margin-top: 4px; }
        .bx_lnx_notes {}
        .bx_lnx_notes span {background-color: #FDFFCC; color: #666; font: 9px Arial; padding:2px;}
        .bx_lnx_tags {}
        .bx_lnx_tags span {background-color: #efefef; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; color: #666; font: 9px Arial; padding: 1px 2px 1px 2px; margin-right: 5px;}
    </style>
```

Against the following HTML

```
<div class="ur_container">
    <ul class="bx_grp" id="grp_1">
        <li>
            <div class="bx_grp_header">
                <span class="bx_grp_title">Personal File</span>
                <span class="bx_grp_options"><a href="#">rename</a> &bull; <a href="#">make private</a> &bull; <a href="#">hide</a href="#"> &bull; <a href="#">delete</a></span>   
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>      
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="bx_lnx" id="lnx_1">
                <li>
                    <div class="bx_lnx_header">
                        <span class="bx_linx_title"><span class="bx_lnx_refno">#3103</span>How to file personal files</span>
                        <span class="bx_lnx_options"><a href="#">edit</a> &bull; <a href="#">move</a> &bull; <a href="#">delete</a></span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="bx_lnx_url">http://www.google.com</li>
                <li class="bx_lnx_notes"><span>search google for this</span></li>
                <li class="bx_lnx_tags"><span>personal</span><span>file</span><span>google</span></li>
            </ul>       
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Which produces this output in Chrome and Fireworks
[alt text http://haberhavadis.com/chff.jpg](http://haberhavadis.com/chff.jpg)

and the following in IE
[alt text http://haberhavadis.com/IE.jpg](http://haberhavadis.com/IE.jpg)

The yellow and red colors was used in order to show that is being going wrong. The yellow part is the undesired one.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please ?

Regards

Comment: I am not using any doctype actually. Would that be a problem?

Comment: Not having a doctype typically causes IE <= 7 to render in quirks mode, I'm not sure quite what IE 8 chooses to do without a valid doctype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>This looks like IE8 rendering in IE7 document mode, which can be triggered a number of ways.</strike>

***(Updated after OP commented that no DOCTYPE is being used.)***

Omitting a DOCTYPE will cause your page to render in *Quirks* mode. See [What happens in Quirks Mode?](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) You are certainly free to do this, but this answer will be based on adding a DOCTYPE so the page will render in *Standards* mode. You can decide for yourself if you want to go this way (see [Choosing the right doctype for your HTML documents](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/14-choosing-the-right-doctype-for-your/).)

I would suggest either HTML 4.01 Strict...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

...or even HTML 5...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

...and the use of a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to catch any markup errors.

Now that we are rendering in Standards mode, we can use the [W3C box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) in which the `width` of an element is inclusive of the `border`, and `padding`, but not the `margin`.

Going to Standards mode alone will take care of the the gap you are seeing in IE8, but you will still see it in IE7 (even in Standards mode--it's a browser bug). Since you are using a fixed width (and assuming <strike>you are rendering in standards mode</strike> you go the Standards mode route), one easy fix is...

```
#lnx_1 {width: 968px;}
```

The width of `968px` comes from **980px** (width of `.ur_container`) **- 2px** (1px of border on each side from `.bx_grp`) **- 10px** (5px padding on each side from `.ur_container ul.bx_lnx`) = **968px**.

See [this page](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200610/closing_the_gap_between_list_items_in_ie/) for more information on this particular IE list item bug fix.

Another change is required when going to Standards mode:

```
.bx_lnx_refno {background-color:#333; color: fff; padding: 1px; margin-right: 5px; }
```

The `color: fff` portion is invalid without the pound sign; change it to `color: #fff`

As for `<span class="bx_lnx_options">` being one line lower than you want, changing to Standards mode will put keep it on the first line in IE8, but not in IE7. Changing the source order would fix this...

```
<span class="bx_lnx_options"><a href="#">edit</a> &bull; <a href="#">move</a> &bull; <a href="#">delete</a></span>
<span class="bx_linx_title"><span class="bx_lnx_refno">#3103</span>How to file personal files</span>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533607/css-three-column-layout-problem/533671#533671) for insight into why this happens.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem to some extend. 
1) Top gap is removed but there is now a little gap on the right. leave that alone, the <span class="bx_lnx_options"> which is floated to the right, still seems one line below where it should be (see the chorme and firefox image where it is at the top-right corner of the red box) any ideas for that?
2) How did you calculate the "968px" ?
3) I visited the link you suggested but thats a much simpler layout. In my case its more complex and whatever I tried either messed up the layout in IE while it corrected it in the others or vice versa...

Comment: @Emin Updated my answer in response to your questions and the comment you made about not using a DOCTYPE

Comment: I really do appreciate the time and effort you put into this in order to solve my problem. Everything works fine now and I now know more of doctypes and other issues. I hope one day I also become an expert and help others (as a payback!) Thanks once again!

@ricebowl. Thank you also for answering. I had no idea how important  (or necessary) the DOCTYPE was!